# Apple Script, Javascript: fill text filed (web form) with data from clipboard

Tags: applescript, copy-paste, javascript

I want to fill a webform (text filed) from a page i open in Safari with the text from a excel cell. I have managed to do a script to copy the cell content to clipboard but i do not know how to use this to fill the form.

I do not have much experience and i found the below code to input a specific text. How do i change it to do what i need?

```
tell application "Safari" 
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('Exampleid').value = "Clipboard";" in document 1 
end tell
```

Note: the script in total is bigger and it goes in a loop each time selecting a different cell in excel to copy into the same form but at a different address.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the cell text to the clipboard, save it in a variable and then apply it to the form.

Here's a helpful [tutorial](http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-fill-out-forms-on-websites-with-applescript/) that will give you the answer, step by step.

The code would be very similar to yours, using the variable:

```
tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "  document.getElementById('" & IdVar & "').value ='" & theCellValue & "';" in document 1
end tell
```

To set the variable form Excel use this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set CellValueX to (value of cell ColX of row RowX)
end tell
```

And, of course, wrapt it all in a repeat loop.

I hope this helps.